# Editing select list content when field settings can no longer be changed

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to change a select list but when I view the field settings I get this message:

`There is data for this field in the database.  The field settings can no longer be changed`

I need to remove a few items and add a new item, what would be the best way to approach this?

I'm thinking of creating a new select list with the new options on it and disabling the old one.  Would that work?  Or am I going to have to manually edit the database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We have a way to do it, but not from the CMS. You can follow the below steps:

- Find a custom module in your project, if not create one.
- Select a hook for your .install file. [Hook_install()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install/7.x), if you are
  creating a new module or [hook_update_N()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x), if you are updating an
  existing module install file.
- Write down some code to update your DB field using available
  [db_update_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_change_field/7.x) function of Drupal.
- Once you done, you either need to install your module or need to run
  the update.php (DB updates) for changes to take place.

This is the proper way to update the field settings when you are getting similar errors in CMS. Hope that helps!